# Can someone explain generic return type of this method in java

Tags: java, generics, java-8

```
    public <R, C> R accept(AstVisitor<R, C> visitor, C context) {
        return visitor.visitStatement(this, context);
    }
    
    protected R visitStatement(Statement node, C context) {
        return this.visitNode(node, context);
    }
```

I understand the return type of this method is generic R. The thing which confuses me is <R, C>, What does "<R, C>" restricts? I will appreciate pointers to a good documentation.

Comment: Hi, I think your case is a subset of a generic class. Is it correct? The <R, C>   public <R, C> R accept is defining two "new potential" generics type: R and C for the method R accept(AstVisitor<R, C> visitor, C context)

Comment: You may want to read the Java Tutorial for [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Angelika Langer also have some [reference examples](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<R,C>` specify generic type parameters and simply allow instances of visitor and context to work regardless of the object with which they were constructed.

So if

```
AstVisitor<Integer, String> = new AstVisitor(....);
String context = "....";
```

Then the method behaves as follows:

```
public Integer accept(AstVisitor<Integer, String> visitor, String context) {
       return ...; // returns an integer.
}
```

Note:  The type parameters allow for the method to receive the arguments and specify a return type.  However, the logic in the method must be appropriate for those types. Otherwise  you will get either a compiler error or a runtime exception.

Here is a simple example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = foo("hello", 1);
    System.out.println(result);
    
    
    int result2 = foo(1, "hello");
    System.out.println(result2);
}
    
public static <R,C> R foo(R r, C c) {
    return r; // just returns the argument
}
```

prints

```
hello
1
```

Since the number `1` above is an `int` and not an `Integer`, it converts it first to  an Integer, then back to an `int` upon return.  It does this because the method expects objects, not primitives.  This is known as `boxing` and `unboxing` which, if you are unfamiliar, you should read about.

Comment: In your example above if you replace the return type of method to just "R" instead of "<R,C> R ", Wouldn’t that work too?

Comment: The `<R,C>` is not part of the return type.  The return type is `R`. The `<R,C>` specify the type parameters  you are going to use.  If you remove them, then the compiler would not know what R and C are.  They would still be required if the return type was void.